# Why is Visual Studio's table adapter query not returning the same data as the stored procedure it represents?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, tableadapter, data-access-layer

I'm using a table adapter in Visual Studio to make a query to a stored procedure in my SQL Server 2005 database.  When I make the call via my website application it returns nothing.  When I make the same call via SQL Server Manager it returns the expected data.

I put a breakpoint on the call to the adapter's `getData` method and looked at all the parameters and their values and matched them in a query from server management to make sure.  I'm sending the following query:

```
getData(string, date, date, int, int?, int?, string, int?, string)
```

further

```
getData('0000-rtg', '1/1/2007', '3/12/2008', 0, null, null, null, null, null)
```

I guess I'm wondering if Visual Studio does something with the `null`'s before it tries to send the query to the SQL server.  If not, how do I fix this problem?

EDIT:
All these values are passed by variables, I just typed what was in those variables at that break point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Sql Profiler to see how the sql sent to sql server actually looks like. This has helped me many times.

Answer (score 1):

Dates need to have quotes around them in SQL else they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio can be funny with query parameters.  Make sure each variable has the correct length and type.  For example, I use several date parameters in a query.  Everytime I edit the query, Visual Studio automatically detects the date parameters and limits the variable to a length of 7.  I pass the date in as "9/12/2009", which gets cut off to "9/12/20", so I need to manually change my date paramters to a length of 10.